# How does one creates Jupyter a notebook from the command line without using the browser?

Tags: command-line, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, org-babel

I am trying to use [ob-ipython](https://github.com/gregsexton/ob-ipython/) in a pure terminal setup, but I don't know any way of creating or starting a notebook engine. It must have the http interface for ob-ipython to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can request `jupyter` to *not* open a browser by passing the argument `--no-browser`.